# How do I tell GCC asm that an input register is clobbered?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to do a 64=32x32 multiply via the x86 `mul` instruction, but I only need the high dword of the result (the `edx` register).  So naturally, I tried listing `edx` as an output register and `eax` as a clobbered register.

This seems natural to me, but `eax` is *also* an input register.  When I try to tell GCC that `eax` is clobbered, it gives an error message.

```cpp
__asm__("mull\t%2" : "=d"(div10) : "%a"(UINT32_C(0x1999999A)), "r"(number)
    : "cc", "rax");
```

If I try that, it throws this error message:

```
divmod10.cpp:76:91: error: can’t find a register in class ‘AREG’ while reloading
‘asm’
divmod10.cpp:76:91: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
```

Omitting it compiles, but breaks the code.  GCC ends up relying upon `eax` not being clobbered, which is incorrect:

```
        movl    $429496730, %eax
#APP
# 76 "divmod10.cpp" 1
        mull    %esi
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        movl    %edx, %esi
#APP
# 78 "divmod10.cpp" 1
        mull    %edx
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
```

How do I do what I want?

Comment: From the docs (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html): `It is not possible to use Clobbers to inform the compiler that the values in these inputs are changing.` Use a junk variable for the output: `__asm__("mull\t%2" : "=d"(div10), "=a"(junk) : "1"(UINT32_C(0x1999999A)), "r"(number) : "cc");`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make a useless temp for the output to go into and the compiler will optimize it out. For example:

```
__asm__("mull\t%2" : "=d"(div10), "=a"((int){0})
    : "a"(UINT32_C(0x1999999A)), "r"(number) : "cc");
```

That's the easiest way I know to handle clobbered inputs.