# How to generically specify AX, EAX or RAX depending on architecture?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to write some inline assembly that works for 16, 32, 64, 128 bit intel machines (128 bit is sometime in the future). The idea is to use a generic register name so the compiler or assembler picks `AX` on 8086 (`-m16`?), `EAX` on i686 (`-m32`), `RAX` on x86_64 (`-m64`), and so on.

I thought I could do it by using `a` register for `ax`, `eax` or `rax`; `b` for `bx`, `ebx` or `rbx`; and so on. However, I'm having trouble calling out the "generic" `a` register in code:

```
unsigned char* ptr = ...;
size_t size = ...;

__asm__ __volatile__
(
    "xor %a, %a"
    "lea ptr, %b\n"
    "lea size, %c\n"

    "1:\n"
    "movb 0, %b(%a)\n"
    "inc %a\n"
    "loop 1b\n"

    : /* no outputs */
    : "b" (ptr), "c" (size)
    : "a", "b", "c", "cc"
 );
```

The compiler is complaining:

```
error: unknown register name 'a' in asm
    : "a", "b", "c", "cc"
```

If I remove the `"a"` from the clobber list (so that it starts with `"b"`), then I get:

```
error: unknown register name 'b' in asm
    : "b", "c", "cc"
```

I've also tried specifying it as `"%a"` in the clobber list, but I get the same error message.

According to [Machine Constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) in the GCC manual, `a` is the `a register`. So I'm pretty sure I got the names right. But I'm also pretty sure I'm doing something wrong or I don't quite understand something in the big picture of things.

**Question**: How do I generically specify the Intel register names so the inline assembly "just works" with `-m32` or `-m64` (or even `-m128` when that day comes)?

---

OS X is 10.8.5, x64, fully patched. Assembler is:

```
$ /usr/bin/as -v
Apple Inc version cctools-855, GNU assembler version 1.38
```

---

Related: in the code above, I'm using `lea` to side step machine word sizes. For example, I'm writing it that way so the generated code is `movl size, %%ecx` (32-bit) or `movq size, %%rcx` (64-bit). I'm not sure if its the recommended way to do it (or if it even works because I have not been able to run it). Corrections, please.

Comment: Well, `expected '(' after 'asm operand'` probably means exactly this. If you provide all what you wrote instead of putting `...` everywhere, we could tell what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks  @glglgl. If its going to be a distraction, then I'll remove it.

Comment: It is not about the distraction, it is abnout the context. What comes before `"xor %0, %0"` in your code? Especially because I think that you are on the right track there...

Comment: @glglgl - nothing comes before the code. It seemed to be a distraction, and its not the primary question, so its gone now. Before it was deleted, it was the same code presented in the body. But `xor %a, %a` was changed to `xor %0, %0` to show an example of what I was having trouble expressing.

Comment: mmm, strange. I should have thought that it would be exactly the right way: use `%0`, `%1` etc. and thus reference the regusters mentionned with `"a"` etc...

Comment: It cannot be generic. AX, EAX, RAX are registers for the various architecture (or at least ABIs) several x86 processors are supporting.

Comment: Only preprocessor `#if defined ... #elif defined ...` comes to mind. It will certainly break on hypothetical future architectures. You could also probably refactor your assembly to use intrinsics instead. They will most certainly be updated for new hardware in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't.
Use architecture specific predefines and copy-paste. Even better use compiler intrinsics or separate asm files.

Some other useful info

- On apple such predefined macro which worked for me is __LP64__ it's set on x86_64 achitecture
  so you code can look like:

  ```
   #ifdef __LP64__
       void myfunctionfor64bitArch()
   #else
       void myfunctionfor32bitArch()
   #endif
  ```

there should also be more correct to use __x86_64__ but I didn't try.

- think why you want cross-platform assembler so much? You code can't be big: ABI differs, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions so your code can't be long in a generic form, assembler is too different
- in recent versions of clang Visual-Studio style assembler works. IMHO it's much more convenient. try

  ```
  __asm
  {
       mov eax, your_variable    ; Get first argument
  }
  ```

what is interesting in clang it works for x64, while in original studio it does only for 32 bits

Comment: *"You just can't"* - Thanks @dev_null. I was not aware I could not do it. For some reason, I thought that's what those registers were for.

Answer (score 4):

You don't appear to check if `(size == 0)` in your code, so I'll follow that assertion. The `__volatile__` will be necessary if any output parameters are updated and not subsequently used - the compiler doesn't know that the the memory `ptr[size]` has been zeroed, and seeing no side-effects, it will simply omit the asm block.

We use 'temporary' arguments so we can update the values and then discard them. The compiler knows the temp arguments have been modified, and seeing they are never used again, doesn't need to maintain those registers. I suggest something like:

```
{
    size_t tmp_size = size;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (

        "%=:\n\t" /* generate a unique label. */

        "sub $1, %0\n\t"
        "movb $0, %1(%0)\n\t" /* 0 -> ptr[size - 1] .. ptr[0] */
        "jnz %=b\n\t" /* jump 'back' */

        : "+r" (tmp_size) : "r" (ptr) : "memory", "cc");
}
```

This also lets the compiler choose the registers, which is preferable. I don't think this is going to give you common 64, 32 (or 16) bit code. You might want to look at [operand modifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#i386Operandmodifiers) for that. Otherwise, you might need 'q' and 'l' suffixes on the instructions for 64 and 32 bit versions respectively.

BTW, `sub/jnz` is typically better on modern processors than `inc/dec` (partial flags stall hazard) and `loop` (complex microcode 'stuff').

Comment: You missed a subtle one: You need the "memory" clobber.  The "+r" simply says you are mucking with the pointer.  To tell it the *contents* are changing, you either need to use the "memory" clobber, or a "m" constraint.  And if you are going to give a link for the operand modifiers, might I suggest the official gcc docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#i386Operandmodifiers

Comment: @DavidWohlferd - thanks. The previous code was incrementing the pointer, rather than using the offset form. Too many edits and too little testing.

Comment: Thanks @Brett - I actually need the `__volatile__` to [ensure the optimizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile) does not remove the ASM code as dead code (its a zeroizer). That's one of the few things I am sure of. I like the routine you're using - its cleaner and it appears to "just work" for different architectures and register sizes.

Comment: @Brett - this is one of those questions where the wrong question was asked... So I have to award someone else the credit even though your answer is most helpful to me. I apologize for that.

Comment: @jww: a byte-at-a-time zeroing loop is pretty terrible.  But if this is used for a single `int` or something, it wouldn't be worth using `rep stosb`.  You can use `* (volatile char*)foo = 0` in C instead of writing asm, though, and as a volatile store it's safe from optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I tried my best, but couldn't come closer than this.

```
#include <stddef.h>

void f(unsigned char* ptr, size_t size) {

__asm__ __volatile__
(
    "xor %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
    "lea ptr, %0\n\t"
    "lea size, %1\n\t"

    "1:\n\t"
    "movb 0, %0\n\t"
    "inc %%eax\n\t"
    "loop 1\n\t"

    : /* no outputs */
    : "b" (ptr), "c" (size)
    : "0", "1", "%eax", "cc"
 );

}
```

It differs from yours a little bit, but shows the right path: obviously, `"a"` cannot be used in the clobber list, whyever. So i did it this way.

Compiling this module with `gcc -S x.c -o-` shows me

```
... [ start of function, irrelevant here ]
#APP
# 5 "x.c" 1
    xor %eax, %eax
    lea ptr, %ebx
    lea size, %ecx
    1:
    movb 0, %ebx
    inc %eax
    loop 1

# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
... [ end of function, irrelevant here ]
```

I hope to have been helpful nevertheless.

---

EDIT: It showed that this is illegal according to the GCC docs. (Although my compiler didn't complain, unlike in the question I linked to.)

So let's try again:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void f(unsigned char* ptr, size_t size) {

uint32_t junk;
size_t countdown;

__asm__ __volatile__
(
    "xor %0, %0\n\t"
    "lea ptr, %2\n\t"
    "lea size, %3\n\t"

    "1:\n\t"
    "movb 0, %2(%0)\n\t"
    "inc %0\n\t"
    "dec %1\n\t"
    "loopnz 1\n\t"

    : "=a" (junk) /* junk output */, "=c" (countdown)
    : "b" (ptr), "c" (size)
    : "cc", "memory"
 );

}
```

(BTW, I added a `dec %1` and a `loopnz` somewhere...)

Comment: It's not legal to mark an operand as both an input *and* clobbered. From manual: "It is not possible to use Clobbers to inform the compiler that the values in these inputs are changing."

Comment: @BrettHale Thank you, that lead me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26942064/296974) which shows some interesting aspects.

Comment: The weird thing is - it's never been 'legal', but for some reason gcc has always let it pass, even though it would seem to be an easy thing to check for. I don't know if the default behaviour is to pretend the register is unchanged (leading to incorrect code if the parameter is used later), or whether it just silently assumes the input is clobbered - and hopefully 'reloads' the value...